# Failing to open files with WindowBuilder on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I get the following error trying to load a file with WindowBuilder:

```
Plug-in org.eclipse.wb.core.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DesignerEditor.
```

What does it mean and what needs to be done?

I am following instructions from Learn Java The Easy Way. I reviewed what I typed a few times but I have been unable to find the reason why the file cannot be opened.

I have confirmed that WindowBuilder is installed. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running Java 9?

Comment: Yes, I have installed and using Java 9.

Comment: This looks like [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522680) which seems to be caused by a bug in the Apache Commons Lang code. It is possible that installing the Java 9.0.1 release from the Oracle site might work round the Apache bug.

Comment: I have updated Java to version 9.0.1
The bug remains existent.